# Instagram API - What Constitutes "Replicating the Functionality"?

Tags: instagram-api

I'm starting work on a project where the client has a homepage designed to display blog posts and IG posts in a 3-wide mosaic sorted by newest posted. The IG posts are all from the website owner's account. The previous shop built this functionality but it is still using the sandbox API.

When looking at the documentation, I saw the following two notes:

1. "Add something unique to the community. Don't use the Instagram APIs to replicate or attempt to replace the functionality or essential user experiences of Instagram.com or any of Instagram's apps."
2. "You cannot replicate the core user experience of the Instagram apps or web site. For example, do not build a media viewer."

My question is, is a mosaic of combined posts - blog and the blog owners IG - presented in a mosaic in violation of these two rules? I'd like to have an idea before I start down the road of registering and attempting to have the functionality approved by instagram.